# How to keep the data on Scope in an Angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I'm learning Ionic and I'm doing a tutorial. Everything was fine until I created a factory that access a webservice.

When I access the variables in the scope they aren't defined or they are simply like how I initialized the variable.

This is the code

**Controller.js**

```
angular.module('songhop.controllers', ['ionic', 'songhop.services'])

/*Controller for the discover page*/
    .controller('DiscoverCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, User, Recommendations) {
      // get our first songs
      Recommendations.getNextSongs()
        .then(function(){
          $scope.currentSong = Recommendations.queue[0];
          console.log($scope.currentSong);
        });

      console.log(Recommendations.queue);
      console.log($scope.currentSong);
      // Fired when a song is favorited or skiped
      $scope.sendFeedback = function (bool){
    Recommendations.nextSong();

    // First add to favorites if they favorited
    if (bool) User.addSongToFavorites($scope.currentSong);

    $scope.currentSong.rated = bool;
    $scope.currentSong.hide = true;

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.currentSong = Recommendations.queue[0];
    }, 250);
  };

})


/*
Controller for the favorites page
*/
.controller('FavoritesCtrl', function($scope, User) {
  // get the list of our favorites from  the user service
  $scope.favorites = User.favorites;

  $scope.removeSong = function(song, index) {
    User.removeSongFromFavorites(song, index);
  };
})
```

**Service.js**

```
  angular.module('songhop.services', []).factory('User', function() {

  var o = {
    favorites: []
  }


  o.addSongToFavorites = function(song){
    // Make sure there is a song to add
    if (!song) return false;

    // Add to favorites array
    o.favorites.unshift(song);
  }

  o.removeSongFromFavorites = function(song, index) {
    // make sure there is a song to remove
    if (!song) return false;

    // remove to favorites array
    o.favorites.splice(index, 1);
  }

  return o
})

.factory('Recommendations', function($http, SERVER) {
  var p = {
    queue: []
  };

  p.getNextSongs = function() {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: SERVER.url + '/recommendations'
    }).success(function(data){
      // merge data into the queue
      p.queue = p.queue.concat(data);
    });
  };

  p.nextSong = function() {
    // pop the index 0 off
    p.queue.shift();

    // low on the queue? lets fill it up
    if (p.queue.length <= 3) {
      p.getNextSongs();
    }

  };
  return p;

})
```

In the console.logs lines that I did for testing, I get the correct data in the first one. The second one is [] and the third one is undefined.

I don't understand why the

```
$scope.currentSong = Recommendations.queue[0];
```

isn't setting the $scope.currentSong variable to what it should since $scope variables should be global, right?

Comment: Are you sure the `console.log` of `$scope.currentSong` isn't executing before the `promise` that is loading your data completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second and third console log do not return you any data because they are executing **before** the promise returned by  ***Recommendations.getNextSongs()*** has resolved.

The first shows you data because you have correctly placed it in a then block, which will only execute when the promise resolves. I.e. when the method ***Recommendations.getNextSongs()*** has finished.

If you updated your code like below, each console will log something:

```
  Recommendations.getNextSongs()
        .then(function(){
          $scope.currentSong = Recommendations.queue[0];
             console.log($scope.currentSong);
             console.log(Recommendations.queue);
              console.log($scope.currentSong);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It is in fact executing before the promise.